# Was bedeutet "Alter" in diesem Kontext?

Tags: vocabulary

Im Buch "Was Ist Macht" von Byung-Chul Han (Reclam, 2023) heisst es

> Unter Macht versteht man gewöhnlich die folgende Kausalrelation: Die
> Macht von *Ego* ist die Ursache, die bei *Alter* gegen dessen Willen
> ein bestimmtes Verhalten bewirkt.  Sie befähigt *Ego* dazu, *seine* Entscheidungen, ohne auf *Alter* Rücksicht nehmen zu müssen,
> durchzusetzen.

Ich kenne das Wort "Alter", wenn es "Anzahl der Lebensjahre" bedeutet.  Aber ich habe nicht nachschlagen können, was der Begriff hier bedeutet.  Ich habe das Treffende in keinem Wörterbuch finden können.  Hat jemand eine Ahnung?

Answer (score 7):

*Ego* ist lateinisch und bedeutet „ich“. [*Alter*](https://www.navigium.de/latein-woerterbuch/alter?wb=gross&nr=1) ist lateinisch und bedeutet „der andere (von zwei)“. Es hat hier nichts mit dem deutschen Wort *Alter* zu tun.

Aus dem Kontext kann man vielleicht erkennen, warum diese lateinischen Pronomen in dem Text als Rollennamen verwendet werden. Das ist eine Entscheidung/Erfindung des Autors und keine übliche Konstruktion im Deutschen.

Comment: Also in diesem Kontext würde es "der/das Andere" bedeuten?  Und so wäre es weniger wahrscheinlich "Alter Ego" (wie unten erwähnt)?

Comment: @Cerulean: Ja. "Ich" und "der Andere" sind die beiden handelnden Personen in dieser Erklärung, was Macht ist. "Alter" ist männlich und Einzahl, also nicht "das Andere", sondern eine Person. Mit dem Begriff "Alter Ego" hat es mE nichts zu tun, das ist übersetzt ein "anderes Ich", um das es hier aber nicht geht. Die Pronomen werden hier benutzt wie "A" und "B" in einem Lehrfall für Juristen. Warum der Autor "Ego" für den Mächtigen und "Alter" für den, über den jemand Macht hat, benutzt, und nicht umgekehrt, kann ich nicht sagen. Dazu müsste man wahrscheinlich das Buch lesen.

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt den Begriff *Alter Ego*, der für eine Art seelenverwandte Person steht. In deinem Text wird dieser zusammenstehende Begriff auseinandergezogen, was streng genommen nicht möglich ist, hier aber als künstlerischer Trick verwendet wird, um die Bedeutung von *Alter Ego* hervorzuheben.

Answer (score 1):

This is Latin for the construct in psychology used for some sort of split personality , see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alter_Ego .